# How to find the power supply type through a fuel gauge?

Tags: android, c++, linux-kernel, driver, battery

I am trying to integrate a BQ27531 fuel gauge into an i.MX6 SOM. The schematic is somewhat like this:
[schematic.png (cropped from http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slusbe7c/slusbe7c.pdf)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK3qR.png)

As shown in the schematic, the BQ24192 charger is not connected to the system's I2C line. The registers in the charger can be accessed via the fuel gauge if necessary. I loaded the BQ27531 driver and the battery fuel gauge shows up in the sysfs:

> root@var_mx6:/ # ls /sys/class/power_supply/
>   bq27531-0

I can now read everything related to the fuel gauge via the sysfs, this includes the battery capacity, current, voltage, temperature etc. 
However, I cannot get the type of the power supply (battery/AC/USB/wireless). This information should come from the charger.

In BatteryMonitor.cpp, I found that the sysfs was expected show a `/sys/class/power_supply/ac/` directory when an AC power source was plugged in.

```
void BatteryMonitor::init(struct healthd_config *hc) {
String8 path;
char pval[PROPERTY_VALUE_MAX];

mHealthdConfig = hc;
DIR* dir = opendir(POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH);
if (dir == NULL) {
    KLOG_ERROR(LOG_TAG, "Could not open %s\n", POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH);
} else {
    struct dirent* entry;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir))) {
        const char* name = entry->d_name;

        if (!strcmp(name, ".") || !strcmp(name, ".."))
            continue;

        // Look for "type" file in each subdirectory
        path.clear();
        path.appendFormat("%s/%s/type", POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH, name);
        switch(readPowerSupplyType(path)) {
        case ANDROID_POWER_SUPPLY_TYPE_AC:
        case ANDROID_POWER_SUPPLY_TYPE_USB:
        case ANDROID_POWER_SUPPLY_TYPE_WIRELESS:
            path.clear();
            path.appendFormat("%s/%s/online", POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH, name);
            if (access(path.string(), R_OK) == 0)
                mChargerNames.add(String8(name));
            break;

        case ANDROID_POWER_SUPPLY_TYPE_BATTERY:
            mBatteryDevicePresent = true;

            if (mHealthdConfig->batteryStatusPath.isEmpty()) {
                path.clear();
                path.appendFormat("%s/%s/status", POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH,
                                  name);
                if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
                    mHealthdConfig->batteryStatusPath = path;
            }

            if (mHealthdConfig->batteryHealthPath.isEmpty()) {
                path.clear();
                path.appendFormat("%s/%s/health", POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH,
                                  name);
                if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
                    mHealthdConfig->batteryHealthPath = path;
            }

            if (mHealthdConfig->batteryPresentPath.isEmpty()) {
                path.clear();
                path.appendFormat("%s/%s/present", POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH,
                                  name);
                if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
                    mHealthdConfig->batteryPresentPath = path;
            }

            if (mHealthdConfig->batteryCapacityPath.isEmpty()) {
                path.clear();
                path.appendFormat("%s/%s/capacity", POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH,
                                  name);
                if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
                    mHealthdConfig->batteryCapacityPath = path;
            }

            if (mHealthdConfig->batteryVoltagePath.isEmpty()) {
                path.clear();
                path.appendFormat("%s/%s/voltage_now",
                                  POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH, name);
                if (access(path, R_OK) == 0) {
                    mHealthdConfig->batteryVoltagePath = path;
                } else {
                    path.clear();
                    path.appendFormat("%s/%s/batt_vol",
                                      POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH, name);
                    if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
                        mHealthdConfig->batteryVoltagePath = path;
                }
            }

            if (mHealthdConfig->batteryCurrentNowPath.isEmpty()) {
                path.clear();
                path.appendFormat("%s/%s/current_now",
                                  POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH, name);
                if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
                    mHealthdConfig->batteryCurrentNowPath = path;
            }

            if (mHealthdConfig->batteryCurrentAvgPath.isEmpty()) {
                path.clear();
                path.appendFormat("%s/%s/current_avg",
                                  POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH, name);
                if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
                    mHealthdConfig->batteryCurrentAvgPath = path;
            }

            if (mHealthdConfig->batteryChargeCounterPath.isEmpty()) {
                path.clear();
                path.appendFormat("%s/%s/charge_counter",
                                  POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH, name);
                if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
                    mHealthdConfig->batteryChargeCounterPath = path;
            }

            if (mHealthdConfig->batteryTemperaturePath.isEmpty()) {
                path.clear();
                path.appendFormat("%s/%s/temp", POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH,
                                  name);
                if (access(path, R_OK) == 0) {
                    mHealthdConfig->batteryTemperaturePath = path;
                } else {
                    path.clear();
                    path.appendFormat("%s/%s/batt_temp",
                                      POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH, name);
                    if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
                        mHealthdConfig->batteryTemperaturePath = path;
                }
            }

            if (mHealthdConfig->batteryTechnologyPath.isEmpty()) {
                path.clear();
                path.appendFormat("%s/%s/technology",
                                  POWER_SUPPLY_SYSFS_PATH, name);
                if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
                    mHealthdConfig->batteryTechnologyPath = path;
            }

            break;

        case ANDROID_POWER_SUPPLY_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
            break;
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

// This indicates that there is no charger driver registered.
// Typically the case for devices which do not have a battery and
// and are always plugged into AC mains.
if (!mChargerNames.size()) {
    KLOG_ERROR(LOG_TAG, "No charger supplies found\n");
    mBatteryFixedCapacity = ALWAYS_PLUGGED_CAPACITY;
    mBatteryFixedTemperature = FAKE_BATTERY_TEMPERATURE;
    mAlwaysPluggedDevice = true;
}
if (!mBatteryDevicePresent) {
    KLOG_WARNING(LOG_TAG, "No battery devices found\n");
    hc->periodic_chores_interval_fast = -1;
    hc->periodic_chores_interval_slow = -1;
} else {
    if (mHealthdConfig->batteryStatusPath.isEmpty())
        KLOG_WARNING(LOG_TAG, "BatteryStatusPath not found\n");
    if (mHealthdConfig->batteryHealthPath.isEmpty())
        KLOG_WARNING(LOG_TAG, "BatteryHealthPath not found\n");
    if (mHealthdConfig->batteryPresentPath.isEmpty())
        KLOG_WARNING(LOG_TAG, "BatteryPresentPath not found\n");
    if (mHealthdConfig->batteryCapacityPath.isEmpty())
        KLOG_WARNING(LOG_TAG, "BatteryCapacityPath not found\n");
    if (mHealthdConfig->batteryVoltagePath.isEmpty())
        KLOG_WARNING(LOG_TAG, "BatteryVoltagePath not found\n");
    if (mHealthdConfig->batteryTemperaturePath.isEmpty())
        KLOG_WARNING(LOG_TAG, "BatteryTemperaturePath not found\n");
    if (mHealthdConfig->batteryTechnologyPath.isEmpty())
        KLOG_WARNING(LOG_TAG, "BatteryTechnologyPath not found\n");
}

if (property_get("ro.boot.fake_battery", pval, NULL) > 0
                                           && strtol(pval, NULL, 10) != 0) {
    mBatteryFixedCapacity = FAKE_BATTERY_CAPACITY;
    mBatteryFixedTemperature = FAKE_BATTERY_TEMPERATURE;
}
}
```

I do not know how to get the AC folder to appear under sysfs. There is no AC driver as far as I know and I cannot load the driver for the charger (BQ24192) directly as it is not connected to the system's I2C bus. How can I find out the power supply type then? The "No charger supplies found" message was produced by the BatteryMonitor by the way.